# how to add new object to xamarin?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhVFn.png)

ni want to add new object to toolbox in xamarin (picture). you can imagination like add new brush to photoshop for drawing. I want create my own object,and add to toolbox. how to create the object? it s like i don't have to code, just add object to controlviewer and done.many object like i want.[enter image description here][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Zws.png( same like xcode, add more object to object library)

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has a [walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/) that explains how to add Custom Controls to the Xamarin Studio designer Toolbox.

The key element is that you have to decorate your class with the following attribute to make it visible to the designer:

```
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
```

Comment: do you have any clue for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665313/getheightforheader-and-getviewforheader-not-called