# GetHeightForHeader and GetViewForHeader not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I am working on a tableview which has two sections. And I would like to add a headerView in the second section header.

I have implemented the following code. It calls `TitleForHeader` but unfortunately neither  `GetHeightForHeader` nor `GetViewForHeader` are getting called at all. Anyone has any clue?

```
public override string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
   if (section == 0)
   {
     return "Details";
   }
   if (section == 1)
   {
     return "Settings";
   }

 return "";
}

public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
       return 0.0001f;
    }
    if (section == 1) 
    {
        return 100.0f;
    }
  return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
}

public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
  if (section == 1) {
    UIView headerView = new UIView (new CGRect (0, 0, (float)tableView.Bounds.Width, (float)tableView.SectionHeaderHeight));
    headerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
    return headerView;
   }
   else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that TitleForHeader and ViewForHeader are mutually exclusive.  Try removing TitleForHeader.

Comment: I tried also by removing `TitleForHeader` and but still it did not come to `GetViewFoHeader` and `GetHeightForHeader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem just realised I was setting the delegate and the source like so:

```
Table.Delegate = new TableDelegate(this); //remove this bit
Table.Source = new TableSource<string>(list, Table);
```

I realised that I should be using only UITableViewSource and not setting both.

> `UITableViewSource` replaces the following two classes, which are still available in Xamarin.iOS but are not normally required:
>
> `UITableViewDataSource` – An Objective-C protocol that is modeled in Xamarin.iOS as an abstract class. Must be subclassed to provide a table with a view for each cell, as well as information about headers, footers and the number of rows and sections in the table.
>
> `UITableViewDelegate` – An Objective-C protocol that is modeled in Xamarin.iOS as a class. Handles selection, editing features and other optional table features.

[Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_1_-_table_parts_and_functionality/#Classes_Overview)

I just moved my rowselected method into my `TableSource` and it now calls the `TitleForHeader` and `GetViewForHeader` methods (they are not mutually exclusive) and **only** set the source no delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I just forgot to set the **delegate** in viewDidLoad

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
     base.ViewDidLoad();

     TableView.DataSource = new YourViewControllerTableDataSource();
     TableView.Delegate = new YourViewControllerTableDelegate();

}
```